# How to upload a file from localhost to a server in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am currently using the line of code below to upload a file into a folder called "uploads" within my application and it works just fine.

```
string fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fullPath);
```

I would now like to know how I can upload to a folder named "uploads" which sits on the D drive on our company server whilst developing on my localhost. The reason for wanting to do this is because I need to use openrowset to extract data from that file into a table on the company server. This is what I had tried assuming global would be different from local I am also assuming that credentials will be needed perhaps I can just get those from my connection string? Please assist

```
string fullPath = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fullPath);
```

Comment: Well, you would need the full URL to the folder that resides on the company server. Also, you need to ensure that you have proper access to read and write to that folder. You cannot directly upload or download something on the server without having proper permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need the "double-back-wack" path as my network team cheerfully likes to call them.

It would look something like this:

```
\\SERVERNAME\MyUploadsFolder
```

Your network team may need to set this path up for you so it hits the correct server drive you are looking for. If you can already access the folder through a mapped drive on your local machine, view where the mapped drive is pointing to, it should be a path similar to what I have above.

So then your code would look like this:

```
string fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\\SERVERNAME\MyUploadsFolder");
```

As mentioned by one of the comments, you would need to make sure that your local Active Directory account that you are running Visual Studio in has the correct permissions to write to that directory. Or you would need to "Impersonate" a user that has access to that folder through C# code. If you are able to login to that server or hit that network drive from your local computer and are able to view the files and make changes to them then you should be able to run it locally. However if you publish the changes to another server the code would no longer be running under your active directory account and you would receive a permission error.